# Nic address spoofing driver doesn't work after restart

Tags: windows, driver, spoofing

https://github.com/btbd/hwid/blob/master/Kernel/main.c

```
VOID SpoofNIC() {
    SwapControl(RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Driver\\nsiproxy"), NsiControl, NsiControlOriginal);

    PVOID base = GetBaseAddress("ndis.sys", 0);
    if (!base) {
        printf("! failed to get \"ndis.sys\" !\n");
        return;
    }

    PNDIS_FILTER_BLOCK ndisGlobalFilterList = FindPatternImage(base, "\x40\x8A\xF0\x48\x8B\x05", "xxxxxx");
    if (ndisGlobalFilterList) {
        PDWORD ndisFilter_IfBlock = FindPatternImage(base, "\x48\x85\x00\x0F\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x33", "xx?xx?????x???xxx");
        if (ndisFilter_IfBlock) {
            DWORD ndisFilter_IfBlock_offset = *(PDWORD)((PBYTE)ndisFilter_IfBlock + 12);

            ndisGlobalFilterList = (PNDIS_FILTER_BLOCK)((PBYTE)ndisGlobalFilterList + 3);
            ndisGlobalFilterList = *(PNDIS_FILTER_BLOCK *)((PBYTE)ndisGlobalFilterList + 7 + *(PINT)((PBYTE)ndisGlobalFilterList + 3));

            DWORD count = 0;
            for (PNDIS_FILTER_BLOCK filter = ndisGlobalFilterList; filter; filter = filter->NextFilter) {
                PNDIS_IF_BLOCK block = *(PNDIS_IF_BLOCK *)((PBYTE)filter + ndisFilter_IfBlock_offset);
                if (block) {
                    PWCHAR copy = SafeCopy(filter->FilterInstanceName->Buffer, MAX_PATH);
                    if (copy) {
                        WCHAR adapter[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
                        swprintf(adapter, L"\\Device\\%ws", TrimGUID(copy, MAX_PATH / 2));
                        ExFreePool(copy);

                        printf("found NIC %ws\n", adapter);

                        UNICODE_STRING name = { 0 };
                        RtlInitUnicodeString(&name, adapter);

                        PFILE_OBJECT file = 0;
                        PDEVICE_OBJECT device = 0;

                        NTSTATUS status = IoGetDeviceObjectPointer(&name, FILE_READ_DATA, &file, &device);
                        if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
                            PDRIVER_OBJECT driver = device->DriverObject;
                            if (driver) {
                                BOOL exists = FALSE;
                                for (DWORD i = 0; i < NICs.Length; ++i) {
                                    if (NICs.Drivers[i].DriverObject == driver) {
                                        exists = TRUE;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (exists) {
                                    printf("%wZ already swapped\n", &driver->DriverName);
                                } else {
                                    PNIC_DRIVER nic = &NICs.Drivers[NICs.Length];
                                    nic->DriverObject = driver;

                                    AppendSwap(driver->DriverName, &driver->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL], NICControl, nic->Original);

                                    ++NICs.Length;
                                }
                            }

                            // Indirectly dereferences device object
                            ObDereferenceObject(file);
                        } else {
                            printf("! failed to get %wZ: %p !\n", &name, status);
                        }
                    }

                    // Current MAC
                    PIF_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_LH addr = &block->ifPhysAddress;
                    SpoofBuffer(SEED, addr->Address, addr->Length);
                    addr = &block->PermanentPhysAddress;
                    SpoofBuffer(SEED, addr->Address, addr->Length);

                    ++count;
                }
            }

            printf("handled %d MACs\n", count);
        } else {
            printf("! failed to find ndisFilter_IfBlock !\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("! failed to find ndisGlobalFilterList !\n");
    }
}
```

I'm using this piece of code to spoof mac address, it works fine after I first installed it, my mac address has been changed.

but after I restart my computer, the mac address returns to what is was before I installed this driver, I had to manually uninstall and install this driver every single time after I restart my computer.

So I checked what's happening, when I restart my computer, the driver jumped over this loop:

```
for (PNDIS_FILTER_BLOCK filter = ndisGlobalFilterList; filter; filter = filter->NextFilter)
```

Seems that ndisGlobalFilterList is null ,but why ,is this by design or is it not achievable to make it work through restarts ?

Comment: What might cause it to act differently when installing it vs when loading it on reboot? Is it executing too early, maybe?